# Excel Userform - highlighted raw data not showing

Tags: excel, vba, userform, conditional-formatting

I couldn't find an answer to an issue I'm having with using User Forms. I have a User Form for inputting data that includes the database log in the lower half of the form to see what has been previously entered. I have a column with a conditional format to highlight duplicates and I'd like those highlights to show up on the User Form so those inputting data can quickly see the duplicate entries. Is there a way to make the highlighted cells appear on the user form using VBA?

[database log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WM17h.jpg)

[user form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oN2Wa.jpg)

I tried finding a vba code that would recognize highlighted cells and show them in the database field on the form.

Comment: If in short what you want to know is : _"can I fill a listbox with color on a specific column & row ?"_, I'm affraid the answer is "_no you can't_".

Comment: yeah that was basically it. The feedback I got from my staff on this form was that they'd like to see the individual rows highlighted for duplicated case numbers. I didn't think it was feasible but I'm still relatively new to VBA so I was hoping I was wrong. I'm toying with trying to add a search feature instead so they can search the list for the case number to see how many are listed as a workaround. Thanks.